# баг при запуске Qt Creator

Tags: linux, qtcreator

Когда Qt Creator запускается, не видны панели. Пробовал переустанавливать, не помогает. Система Linux Astra [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

QOpenGLContext :: makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x2ba1040(тут разные номера ошибок)
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed

Comment: Запустите из консоли, и туда "плюнет" ошибки. Не сможете сами понять, дайте вывод сюда.

Comment: Sey Dee  - как мне запустить Qt Creator  в консоле ?......если я указываю путь до ярлыка и в консоле выдаётся :"отказано в доступе". Всё это я делаю под root пользователем

Comment: скорее всего у вас пакет называется qt-creator. Дайте просто в консоле >qt-creator от обычного пользователя, или наберите в консоле qt и потом кнопку Tab на клавише_в некоторых дистрах нужно 2 раза tab нажать, чтобы вывести все пакеты) - и ищите свой пакет creator, а потом его по имени и запустите. Далее смотрите вывод

Comment: QOpenGLContext :: makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x2ba1040                                                                                           composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed

Comment: проблема из за некоректно настроенного драйвера видео. Идите к ним на сайт - http://wiki.astralinux.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1212444 и найдите драйвер. И проверяйте, что бы opengl работал хорошо. Либо ставьте нормальный линукс.

Comment: KoVadim - у меня NVIDIA GeForce GTX 650 версия Linux CE 1.11 (orel) / я не совсем понял что делать ... попробовал заменить файл 
В каталог /etc/X11/fly-dm положить файл Xsetup..... не помогло

Comment: перезапускать пробовали?

Comment: KoVadim - да пробовал

Answer (score 0):

У меня такой баг был

```
QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x5f70a667ef10
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x5f70a667ef10
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x5f70a667ef10
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent() called with non-opengl surface 0x5f70a667ef10
composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
```

тут прочёл https://wiki.astralinux.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=43614493

И воспользовался первым советом.

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
QApplication app(argc, argv);
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_ForceRasterWidgets, false);
....
}

Заработало

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]